# Beta channel for Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon

Is there a way to create two separate update channels for a Firefox extension that will serve as stable and beta? [This article](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/policies/maintenance#beta-addons) show the way for those who use AMO to publish their extensions. I use my own hosting and I'd like to do it using update manifest. If I describe several versions there, the newest one is downloaded, even if there's a or b suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox will always install the highest compatible version it finds in an update manifest, there is no built-in channel mechanism for extensions. So to implement different channels you have to make sure that extensions on different channels will get different update manifests. AMO does that by looking at the extension version requesting the update manifest (which it can see because the default `updateURL` value contains `version=%ITEM_VERSION%` parameter), versions ending with `aNN` or `bNN` get a different update suggested than regular versions. You could implement a similar mechanism on your server. Personally, I chose a simpler route, one that can work with a static `update.rdf` on the server - my build scripts will simply put a different `updateURL` value into `install.rdf` depending on whether I am building a release version or a test build.